# function that process multilple lines and/or single line in a file

Tags: python, file, twitter

if i have a file, how should i implement a function so that it can both read single and multiple lines. for example:

```
TimC
Tim Cxe
USA
http://www.TimTimTim.com
TimTim facebook!
ENDBIO
Charles
Dwight
END
Mcdon
Mcdonald 
Africa
      # website in here is empty, but we still need to consider it
      # bio in here is empty, but we need to include this in the dict
      # bio can be multiple lines
ENDBIO
Moon
King
END
etc
```

I am just wondering if anyone could use some python beginner keywords (like dont use yield,break, continue).

In my own version, I actually defined 4 functions. 3 of the 4 functions are helper functions.

and i want a function to return:

```
dict = {'TimC':{'name':Tim Cxd, 'location':'USA', 'Web':'http://www.TimTimTim.com', 'bio':'TimTim facebook!','follows': ['Charles','Dwight']}, 'Mcdon':{'name':Mcdonald , 'location':'Africa', 'Web':'', 'bio':'','follows': ['Moon','King']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import izip

line_meanings = ("name", "location", "web")
result = {}
user = None

def readClean(iterable, sentinel=None):
    for line in iterable:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == sentinel:
            break
        yield line

while True:
    line = yourfile.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue
    user = result[line] = {}
    user.update(izip(line_meanings, readClean(yourfile)))
    user['bio'] = list(readClean(yourfile, 'ENDBIO'))
    user['follows'] = set(readClean(yourfile, 'END'))

print result
```

---

```
{'Mcdon': {'bio': [''],
           'follows': set(['King', 'Moon']),
           'location': 'Africa',
           'name': 'Mcdonald',
           'web': ''},
 'TimC': {'bio': ['TimTim facebook!'],
          'follows': set(['Charles', 'Dwight']),
          'location': 'USA',
          'name': 'Tim Cxe',
          'web': 'http://www.TimTimTim.com'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the file collecting the various pieces of data, and yield it when you reach an appropriate sentinel.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def bio_gen(it, sentinel="END"):
    def read_line():
        return next(it).partition("#")[0].strip() 

    while True:
        key = read_line()
        ret = {
            'name': read_line(),
            'location': read_line(),
            'website': read_line(),
            'bio': read_line(),
            'follows': []}
        next(it)                    #skip the ENDBIO line
        while True:
            line = read_line()
            if line == sentinel:
                yield key, ret
                break
            ret['follows'].append(line)

all_bios = dict(bio_gen(sys.stdin))
import pprint
pprint.pprint(all_bios)
```

---

```
{'Mcdon': {'bio': '',
           'follows': ['Moon', 'King'],
           'location': 'Africa',
           'name': 'Mcdonald',
           'website': ''},
 'TimC': {'bio': 'TimTim facebook!',
          'follows': ['Charles', 'Dwight'],
          'location': 'USA',
          'name': 'Tim Cxe',
          'website': 'http://www.TimTimTim.com'}}
```

Comment: code does not consider that the `bio` could be more than 1 line up to `ENDBIO`

Comment: @noskio, correct, the question is underspecified, but the OP indicates that the bio should be a string, not a list. I chose to refuse the temtation to guess. When the question is updated to show what should happen if there is more than one line of bio, I can update my answer